# How to know if print operation was cancelled?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsprintoperation, nsprintinfo

I am using (NSPrintOperation *)printOperationWithView:(NSView *)aView printInfo:(NSPrintInfo *)aPrintInfo method to print a view in my OS X app. All works as expected. Is there a way to catch the event when the user has cancelled the print operation by clicking on the "cancel" button on the print panel? I have been searching here, Apple's printing programming guide and the web but found nothing so far. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I added a selector to print operation method to catch the event when the printPanelDidEnd:
`[printOp runOperationModalForWindow:myWindow delegate:self didRunSelector:@selector(printPanelDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:) contextInfo:nil];`

and then:

`- (void)printPanelDidEnd:(NSPrintPanel *)printPanel returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo {
    if (returnCode == NSCancelButton) {
        NSLog(@"Cancel button was selected");
    }
}`

Comment: The return value of `NSPrintOperation.run()` also contains `false` if the user has canceled the print dialog.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsprintoperation/1532039-run